# How To write an action for a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-partialview

```
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

 var us = from u in db.Users
             join s in db.Designations
             on new { id = u.DesignationID } equals new { id = s.DesignationID }
             where u.Id == currentUserId
             select new ViewEmployees
             {
                 EmployeeCode = u.UserName,
                 EmployeeName = u.Name,
                 Father_Name = u.Father_Name,
                 DesignationName = s.DesignationName,
                 EmployeeType = u.EmployeeType,
                 Email = u.Email,
                 Mobile = u.Mobile
             };
```

I want to use the output of it as a partial view on another View...
how can i write controller for it..
ActionResult or something Else....?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your value to partialview first give the path and then pass your model and in partial view bind the related model!

```
 public ActionResult YourMethodName()
    {
     ViewEmployees us = from u in db.Users
                         join s in db.Designations
                         on new { id = u.DesignationID } equals new { id = s.DesignationID }
                         where u.Id == currentUserId
                         select new ViewEmployees
                         {

                             EmployeeCode = u.UserName,
                             EmployeeName = u.Name,
                             Father_Name = u.Father_Name,
                             DesignationName = s.DesignationName,
                             EmployeeType = u.EmployeeType,
                             Email = u.Email,
                             Mobile = u.Mobile

                         };

        return PartialView("~/PartialViewName", us);
    }
```

and in your partial view

```
@model eHRManager.Models.ViewEmployees
```

Comment: Err0r::The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'eHRManager.Models.ViewEmployees' @Neel

Comment: how is it possible becoz we r passing ViewEmployees in model how it could be Partialviewresult..bulid and debug and tell me what comes in "us" variable? @Usman407

Comment: Even if the types match, you can get this error when a null is passed to a partial view @Usman407

Comment: {System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<eHRManager.Models.ViewEmployees>}
@Neel

Comment: Also shows an Error on the
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
which is written before the Querry...!
Error:  ""Object reference not set to an instance of an object.""

Comment: according to ur last query I can say that you are passing null value to partial view coz if ur getting error before query then how u can say ur model is loaded..put debug point on us and look what "us" is having @Usman407

Comment: Error on the string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();! Error: ""Object reference not set to an instance of an object."" @Neel

Comment: I guess you are getting ur User property as null..i guess you will have to manage session properly

Comment: I callaed it another Action of same controller where it works perfect... @Neel